# Trying to Implement power and factorial functions recursively. C++

Tags: c++, function

All ive got so far are the definitions.

```
double power(double base, int exponent);

double factorial(double n);
```

And after this i am completely lost and I'm looking for ideas.

Comment: This has never been asked before in the history of SO or Google. :-~

Comment: But my suggestion is you read your lecture notes about recursion again.

Comment: I did but i did not understand exactly what it was expecting in power and factorial functions. I understand recursion but i am having an off day. Skilldrick cleared it up... Now i just feel stupid lol...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, 3^4 is 3 * 3 * 3 * 3. Which is 3 * 3^3. 3^3 is 3 * 3^2. 3^2 is 3 * 3^1. 3^1 is 3.

5! is 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1. Which is 5 * 4!. 4! is 4 * 3!. 3! is 3 * 2!. 2! is 2 * 1!. 1!  is 1.

That should give you enough to be getting on with...

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading these:

- [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)
- [Factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Definition)

Answer (score 0):

```
int factorial(int n){
if(n==0) return 1;
else return n*factorial(n-1);}


int power(int number, int p){
      if(p==1) return number;
      else return number*power(number, p-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double power(double base, int exponent)
{
     if (exponent == 0) 
          return 1;
     else
          return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
}

double factorial(double n)
{
     if (n == 0) 
          return 1;
     else
          return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: or `if (exponent == 1) return base;`?

Comment: Yes :) It avoids additional multiplication. I`ve missed that.

Comment: @Skilldrick then it won't work for x^0; though it will correctly handle 0^0 is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try solving this without using recursion first (if you were actually writing these functions for production code, recursion would hurt their performance anyway).  After you get that working, it should be a simple matter to convert it to a recursive algorithm.

HINT:

N! = N * (N-1)!

N^P = product from 1 to P of N

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else seems to assume exp is positive.  Possibly could modify to handle 0^0 properly as a NaN rather than 1, if that's important to your application.

```
double int_power(double base, int exp) {
    if (exp == 0) 
        return 1;
    if (exp > 0)
        return base*int_power(base, exp-1);
    else
        return int_power(base, exp+1)/base;
}
```