# How do you implement the factorial function in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, api-design

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Calculating large factorials in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098319/calculating-large-factorials-in-c)
>   [Howto compute the factorial of x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786207/howto-compute-the-factorial-of-x)

How do you implement the factorial function in C++? And by this I mean properly implement it using whatever argument checking and error handling logic is appropriate for a general purpose math library in C++.

Comment: more similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349505/trying-to-implement-power-and-factorial-functions-recursively-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977715/calculating-and-printing-factorial-at-compile-time-in-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966077/calculate-the-factorial-of-an-arbitrarily-large-number-showing-all-the-digits

Comment: Your profile shows that you're a C# programmer; I doubt the C++ design would be that different.

Comment: Strangely, none of the suggested duplicates looks to me like it's really an exact duplicate of this one. One is asking about using big nums, another using template metaprogramming, and one specifically about a recursive implementation. None of them is just the basic question of how to implement factorial.

Comment: @Jerry: If you can calculate the factorial of a large number, then the rest will fall into place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966077/calculate-the-factorial-of-an-arbitrarily-large-number-showing-all-the-digits

Comment: @0A0D: while true, it looked to me like those questions really came down to "how do I write and/or where do I find bignum code?", and factorial was almost incidental -- it's just a function that happens to produce large integers.

Comment: @Jerry: here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786207/howto-compute-the-factorial-of-x

Comment: @0A0D: Now, that one I'll buy as being an exact duplicate (and have voted to close accordingly).

Comment: None of those are exact duplicates because they all ignore my main question about error handling.

Answer (score 38):

Recursive:

```
unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) 
{
    if (n == 0)
       return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Iterative:

```
unsigned int iter_factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int ret = 1;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        ret *= i;
    return ret;
}
```

Compile time:

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial 
{
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

void foo()
{
    int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
    int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
}
```

Comment: This uses some really unnecessary recursion.

Comment: you can easily apply the iterative approach also.

Comment: And where is the error handling?

Comment: @Jonathan the question was edited after my answer and updated with error handling req I suppose

Answer (score 27):

Besides the obvious loops and recursions, modern C++ compilers support the gamma function as `tgamma()`, closely related to factorial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::tgamma(n+1) << '\n';
}
```

test run: https://ideone.com/TiUQ3

Comment: That is useless in teaching how to do error handling in this kind of function.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: What kind of "error handling"? If you were asking how to restrict the acceptable arguments to permit only the unsigned integers for which the result is exactly representable as a value of a given type, then the answer would be an implementation of `boost::math::factorial`.

Comment: @Cubbi I believe http://ideone.com wrecked your code.

Comment: @Cubbi So I have no right to ask this, but we're discussing one of your http://en.cppreference.com edits, and I thought you might be willing to come clarify for us: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38402133/2642059

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at `boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp` if you have Boost installed. You can read about it at: [Boost Factorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/factorials/sf_factorial.html)